# Like bundle plugin in visual studio 2022 Are there any plugins available for Rider as well?

Tags: bundle, rider, jetbrains-rider

like bundle plugin in visual studio 2022 ( https://github.com/failwyn/BundlerMinifier )

Are there any plugins available for Rider as well?

If I have a bundleconfig.json file in my project,

Whenever I edit the source, I need a plugin that bundles and minifies the JavaScript files.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any 3rd party out-of-the-box minify plugins for Rider, but you can use *File Watchers* (using UglifyJs) to achieve the same goal.

[Guide to setup Rider UglifyJs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Minifying_JavaScript.html).

Note that you will need:

- Node.js installed on your machine.
- UglifyJs installed `npm install --g uglify-js`
- Javascipt & Typescript plugin enabled in Rider.
- 'File Watchers' plugin enabled.

I've used this before and it works without issues. Just needs tweaking to suit your needs (such as file watch scopes, output directory, etc).